# ASP NET get interface implementations

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, .net-4.7.2

I want to retrieve a list of my interface implementations for my `.NET 4.7.2` application:

```
 var entityNames = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                    .Where(x => typeof(IAggregateRoot).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
                    .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Calling ToList() will cause exception:
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, [...]"

How do I solve this? What's the problem here?

Comment: please specify version of .NET, is it core or framework?

Comment: yes sure it's .NET 4.7.2

Comment: Could this be realted to a property setting "Copy Local" ?